# Adding legends into a Graph made using Matplotlib and Numpy (multiple plots from a txt file)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, legend

I had some really good help from here when I asked a question before so I thought I'd jump on again to get some help, here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\Chloe\Desktop")
data=np.loadtxt("tree_rings.txt")
for column in data.T[1:]:
    plt.plot(data[:,0],column)
plt.title("Growth of Tree Rings Over Time")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Size of Tree Rings (mm)")
plt.show()
```

How do I go about adding legends for each line in the graph, there are 3 lines (sample 1, sample 2 and sample 3), I'm mostly confused on how to specify which line corresponds to which set of data. The data is set out in 4 columns, the first is the year which corresponds to the x axis so isn't plotted and the 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns are plotted as lines on the graph. I'm really new to python so thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your data have column names? If so you can use [`np.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) like this:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('tree_rings.csv',delimiter=',',names=True)
```

To answer your question though, you'd use `label` and `plt.legend()` like this:

```
fields = [field for field in data.dtype.fields.keys() if 'Width' in field]
for field in fields:
    plt.plot(data['Year'],data[field],label=field)
#                                     ^^^^^
plt.title("Growth of Tree Rings Over Time")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Size of Tree Rings (mm)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]